# page-break-after not working when content 's created dynamically via AJAX

Tags: css, dom, printing, media-queries, page-break

When loading dynamic rows via ajax the `@media print -- page-break-after` is not working.

It works on all other elements that are not created dynamically. I'm loading rows for a report and after every 15th row I add a `<div class='page'></div>` element. Rows loaded via ajax doesn't seem to work.

```
@media print {

    .page{
       page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

The page breaks fine on elements with 'page' class that were not loaded via ajax, just those. I presume it is not binding to the DOM but don't know how to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent container is `display: flex;` it won't work.

When using `page-break-after` make sure the parent container has `display: block;`